# How to get Effective User Name and Schduling Class for a process using bash - linux

Tags: linux, bash, scheduling

I'm trying to write a bash script that takes a process ID as the user input and prints out information about that process such as the *nice value, priority*...etc. 
I almost got all what I need with help from this site: http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc

However, I couldn't find from where I can get the *effective user name* and the *scheduling class* of the process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The negated scheduling priority can be found as the 18th field of `/proc/[pid]/stat` as detailed in your link.

```
cat /proc/207/stat | cut -d' ' -f18
```

As for the owner of the process, it's the owner of the `/proc/[pid]` directory, or of any file in it.

```
stat -c "%U" /proc/207/
```

---

Edit : removed my scheduling priority calculation because I don't know the first thing about it and might misinterpret the documentation. I'll just leave where the negated one can be found.